# Returning object type Rally

Tags: rally

So I have this query using Rally:

```
query_result = stuff.slm.find(:hierarchical_requirement, :project => project, :workspace => stuff.workspace, :project_scope_up => false, :project_scope_down => true){ equal :name, parent_name.strip }
```

and then I do,

```
parent = query_result.results.first
```

and I am curious to know what kind of object is assigned to the parent. I am not on the exceptions list in Rally so unable to run the script. But I am writing an SSO integration for this script and having some problems. I feel my problem would  be solved if I get to inspect the "parent" because the function is returning this "parent". If anyone has any information on this , please share. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A story (HierarchicalRequirement) object is assigned. Using [Rally Ruby REST toolkit](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForRuby)

The code below prints:

```
my_story: abc, FormattedID: US86, _ref:https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement/12891971030
```

.

```
@rally = RallyAPI::RallyRestJson.new(config)
some_name = "abc"
query = RallyAPI::RallyQuery.new()
query.type = :story
query.fetch = "FormattedID"
query.query_string = "(Name = \"#{some_name}\")"
results = @rally.find(query)

my_story = results.first
puts "my_story: #{my_story}, FormattedID: #{my_story["FormattedID"]}, _ref:#{my_story["_ref"]}"
```

If in your code you try to find a user story based on FormattedID, here is an example. It does not really matter if it is a parent or not, since a parent of a story is a story, and I used "story" instead of "parent" in my script for clarity. A FormattedID is entered as a command line argument in this example. Notice I use `story = result.first`, and not `story=result`. Here is a screenshot of the output:

[image]

```
require 'rally_api'

#Setup custom app information
headers = RallyAPI::CustomHttpHeader.new()
headers.name = "find story"
headers.vendor = "Nick M RallyLab"
headers.version = "1.0"

# Connection to Rally
config = {:base_url => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm"}
config[:username] = "user@co.com"
config[:password] = "secret"
config[:workspace] = "X"
config[:project] = "Y"
config[:version] = "v2.0"
config[:headers] = headers #from RallyAPI::CustomHttpHeader.new()

unless ARGV.length == 1
  puts "enter one argument, e.g. US123, with no spaces"
  exit
end

story = nil
story_id = ARGV[0]
puts "find story by FormattedID: #{story_id}"

@rally = RallyAPI::RallyRestJson.new(config)

query = RallyAPI::RallyQuery.new()
query.type = :story
query.fetch = "Name,FormattedID,ScheduleState"
query.workspace = {"_ref" => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/1111.js" } 
query.project = {"_ref" => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/project/2222.js" } 
query.project_scope_up = true
query.project_scope_down = true

query.query_string = "(FormattedID = \"#{story_id}\")"  

result = @rally.find(query)

if(result.length > 0)
    puts "found the story"
    story = result.first
    puts "FormattedID: #{story["FormattedID"]}, Name: #{story["Name"]}, ScheduleState: #{story["ScheduleState"]}"
else
   puts "did not find a story with FormattedID #{story_id}" 
end 
puts story.class
puts story.inspect
```

Comment: When I try to return this object from my method, I get this error: {:errors=>["Cannot parse object reference from \"forth\""], :warnings=>["API status is Deprecated and will become Not Supported on 10/26/2013"]}

I am not sure if you could help me completely since I have not shared the code here, but I think many people have faced this error before specially with the Rally-Excel plugin. Can you suggest me something on what could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Are you using rally_api or the unsupported rally_rest_api? Can you try my code and see if it works for you? I am afraid I have not seen questions about Excel plugin and Ruby.

Comment: Your code does work, however my pre-existing code doesn't work and I get a "Cannot parse object reference " error. I am not able to understand the problem. Do you know what the error means?

Comment: You may try `puts parent.class` to see what kind of object is parent, but the error indicates that query_result is null. I would suggest using rally_api instead of the unsupported rally_rest_api.

Comment: I did that modification, now using Rally API with SSO, but still get the same result.

Comment: Rally REST toolkits (for Ruby, .NET and Java) do not support SSO yet, there is no built-in support for SSO in rally_api gem (or older rally_rest_api). I understand that you're writing your own. Does it fail with and without SSO, or only with SSO? You said that my code worked for you. How different is your code? Is there a small script where you can replicate the issue, without SSO and post here?

Comment: My organization has provided me a rally sso gem that I am currently using . I am integrating a code (this code uses REST toolkit) that requires rally access, so that it can now work using the SSO gem. Apart from this, I tried running the original script which is based on REST toolkit ( ignoring SSO ) and I get an error as  
    <OperationResultError>Cannot parse input stream due to unexpected error as XML document: empty String</OperationResultError>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38623/discussion-between-nickm-and-rohan-dalvi)